Is it okay to ask for tutoring in a chatroom?
There is a particular user who has helped a lot of a niche area of questions on this website. I am preparing for a competitive exam in a couple of months and I do have some more questions which may not be entirely appropriate for the website. I was wondering if it would be appropriate that I invite him in a chatroom where I ask if he would be interesting in tutoring for several similar courses.
I initially asked about the appropriateness of this action to StackExchange and I got the following response:

This doesn't really answer my question. I was wondering if someone could clarify this for me here.
Question: Is creating a chatroom in which one asks another user about possible tutoring against the rules/not ok?

Can someone explain the downvote? I am asking here if the question is appropriate.

This kind of thing is fine, although I wonder if you'll find chat slightly tedious. If the user agrees you might consider meeting them privately outside the site.

Thank you for the clarification! Feel free to post this as an answer.

Thanks, I'll wait for a moderator to come in with an official reply.

I can't answer your specific question as to how it pertains to the site rules. That being said, tutoring someone is a service that is worth money. If someone asked me to tutor them for free I'd find that presumptuous. I assume that you are intending to offer financial compensation?

Are private chatrooms like this one possible?

@ТymaGaidash, no, private chatrooms are not available.  Chatrooms are required to be publicly visible, to support moderation (with certain narrow exceptions that do not apply here).

@ТymaGaidash Private chatrooms can be created only by moderators. (Moreover, they are usually short-lived - they are frozen if a mod doesn't post. Regular users can create gallery chat rooms - they are visible to everybody, but only some users are allowed to post in the room.

I am not sure how such an invitation will be received.  It is beyond the purpose of this website.  Some people might be OK with receiving such an invitation, some might not and might view the invitation as unwanted.  I don't know if there is an official policy.  If no one else is aware of a policy, I'd suggest you use your best judgement.

Hi, thank you for this answer. I just hope not to me breaking the websites rules. If I end up asking I will try to do it in the most polite/no answer requiring way.
